# Find difference in two set of files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, diff

I have two sets of files containing ip addresses 

file 1

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

file 2

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

I need to compare two file and print the entry present in file 1 but not in file 2,
that is desire output should be

```
3.3.3.3
```

Comment: Look at the "Set Complement" section of the accepted answer to the question this is marked a duplicate of.

Comment: Try the man page for the `comm` command. Note it only works for sorted files (which yours appear to be). If this is not strictly correct, you would need to pre-sort both files.

Comment: Anyway: `diff <(sort f1) <(sort f2) |grep "<"|cut -d" " -f 2`

Comment: @K-att- You would not need `grep` nor `cut` if you use `comm` in place of `diff`.  The `diff` utility is really only useful to visually inspect differences between files or for generating patches. Note too that in _the general case_, your `grep` would match the `<` character anywhere on the line, and the `cut` command would need to be adjusted if the lines contain spaces.

Comment: Indeed. I thought it's a special file, but you're right.